# Consuming SOAP endpoint with Zeep/WSDL

Tags: python, soap, xsd, wsdl, zeep

I'm writing a quick tool to submit jobs through a SOAP API.

I've done this in the past with Zeep but seem to be having issues with this one endpoint that's using xsd in the WSDL.

Here's what I have so far (excluding basic zeep imports):

```
client = Client("wsdl/create_works_orders_definition.wsdl")
    with client.settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True, xsd_ignore_sequence_order=True):
        request = zeep.xsd.Element('SX3_XML_DOCUMENT',
                    zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                        zeep.xsd.Sequence([
                            zeep.xsd.Element('SX3_HEADER',
                                zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                                    zeep.xsd.Element('API',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                    zeep.xsd.Element('REQUESTOR',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                    zeep.xsd.Element('REQUEST_USER',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                    zeep.xsd.Element('REQUEST_PASSWORD',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                ])
                            ),
                            zeep.xsd.Element(
                                'SX3_BODY',
                                zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                                    zeep.xsd.Element('CreateWorksOrders',
                                        zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('ExternalReference',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('PropertyReference',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('WorkProgramme',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('ContractorSite',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('RaisedDateTime',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('PriorityCode',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('TargetDatetime',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('LocationNotes',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('AccessNotes',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('AccessAm',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('AccessPm',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                            zeep.xsd.Element('WoDescription',zeep.xsd.String()),
                                        ])
                                    ),
                                ])
                            ),
                        ])
                    ])
                )


        request_body = request(SX3_HEADER={'API':'','REQUESTOR':'','REQUEST_USER':'','REQUEST_PASSWORD':''},
                              SX3_BODY={'ExternalReference': '', 
                                        'PropertyReference':'', 
                                        'WorkProgramme':'', 
                                        'ContractorSite':'', 
                                        'RaisedDateTime': '',
                                        'PriorityCode':'', 
                                        'TargetDatetime': '', 
                                        'LocationNotes':'', 
                                        'AccessNotes':'', 
                                        'AccessAm':'', 
                                        'AccessPm':'', 
                                        'WoDescription':''})

        create = client.service.CreateWorksOrders(
            request_body,
        )
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to test:

```
ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ContractorSite'. Signature: `CreateWorksOrders: {ExternalReference: xsd:string, PropertyReference: xsd:string, WorkProgramme: xsd:string, ContractorSite: xsd:string, RaisedDateTime: xsd:string, PriorityCode: xsd:string, TargetDatetime: xsd:string, LocationNotes: xsd:string, AccessNotes: xsd:string, AccessAm: xsd:string, AccessPm: xsd:string, WoDescription: xsd:string}`
```

The wsdl is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NIfMqiWCsOGP9rXHTmbecKABAYMw3D4J/view?usp=sharing

It's long so I didn't want to copy and paste the whole thing.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance